# How to webhost a war file

Tags: java, mysql, hosting, web-hosting

Hi after completing my first java web application (it's small application) uses the local server jetty server and database is MySQL.

How to host war file on web server.

any suggestions for tutorials or links please share...

i googled it but lot of unwanted items are there so please help if you know about his please share answers.

Comment: Do not keep asking the same things day after day. Edit your question from yesterday and wait for it. Add a bounty to it if you really can not find it.

Comment: This is a question to find a PaaS provider. You can use the [PaaSFinder](https://paasfinder.org/filter) to search for possible vendors. Query for Runtimes: Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I do not know how to host from localhost a ".war" file, but if you want to be your web application online, you can use Amazon Web Service.

1. go to https://console.aws.amazon.com and then create a free account (account creation process may be changed since it uses 2-step verification).
2. sign in to Amazon AWS from https://console.aws.amazon.com and find "ElasticBeans Talk" under "Deployment & Management".
3. After that you may see an empty page, just click "Create a new Application" from right corner side of the page. Enter your information and then just simply click your new created environment.
4. After that you can upload and deploy ".war" files to this free account.

***Warning!***
Please first read the Pricing page of https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ in order to learn about pricing of Amazon Web Services. If you do not intentionally click an unfree service, it gets the money without asking your permission from your credit card. Amazon Inc. assume that you know about which service is free and if it is not free they assume you know about how much it costs.